# How do I keep track of the bandwidth usage through my Airport Extreme wireless router?

Tags: airport, network

I have 3 Macs, 1 iPad, and 1 Apple TV (using HD Netflix, mostly).

I need to keep an eye on bandwidth usage.  What is the best way to monitor the bandwidth usage (preferably per device) that passes through my Airport Extreme router?

Thanks!

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Airport Express/Extreme allows monitoring via SNMP if you enable it via the Airport Configuration Utility (version 5.6 ONLY).

Apple removed advanced configuration parameters from Airport Configuration Utility 6.0. [Please download a version 5.6 of the utility from Apple’s support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1482) to get a full access to all configuration parameters of your router. **SNMP configuration** is located under **Advanced** settings.

From there, ANY snmp polling engine can get traffic as a whole.

You would be hard-pressed to find anything that could differenciate traffic between devices that isn't a real router (Cisco, etc) or custom built Linux box.

I just found this during a quick serach: [NetUseApp](http://www.netuseapp.com/) via [iTunes Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id440301281?mt=12) allows you to monitor any SNMP device with a pretty interface.

Comment: If you are running the latest version of OS X you cannot install version 5.6

Comment: That is true @nomad33fw  - the installer won't run, but you can bypass the installer and get it to function. Also - it's best to be specific what "latest" means. Some people have pre-release access and as the post ages - latest doesn't mean what it might mean today.